# Slim PHP Upload target path is not writable

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, slim

I am using `Slim 3 PHP` to write video data to my `iOS` app. for some reason I receive an error when trying to write the data to my `MySQL` database.

I have no issue with my image endpoint just my video endpoint.

My code is as follows:

```
function uploadEventVideo($req, $res, $args) {
global $db;

$user_id = validateUserAuthentication($req);
if($user_id) {
    $files = $req->getUploadedFiles();

    if (isset($files['media_photo'])) {
        $media_photo_url = 'Photo_' . generateRandomString(40) . '.jpg';
        $files['media_photo']->moveTo('assets/images/' . $media_photo_url);
    } else {
        $media_photo_url = '';
    }

    if (isset($files['media_video'])) {
        $media_video_url = 'Video_' . generateRandomString(40) . '.mov';
        $files['media_video']->moveTo('assets/videos/' . $media_video_url);
    } else {
        $media_video_url = '';
    }

    $query = $db->prepare('insert into tblEventMedia (media_user_id,
                                                      media_event_id,
                                                      media_photo_url,
                                                      media_video_url,
                                                      media_type)
                                              values (:media_user_id,
                                                      :media_event_id,
                                                      :media_photo_url,
                                                      :media_video_url,
                                                      "VIDEO")');
    $query->bindParam(':media_user_id', $user_id);
    $query->bindParam(':media_event_id', $args['id']);
    $query->bindParam(':media_photo_url', $media_photo_url);
    $query->bindParam(':media_video_url', $media_video_url);
    if($query->execute()) {
        $query = $db->prepare('select * from tblEventMedia where media_id = :media_id');
        $query->bindParam(':media_id', $db->lastInsertId());
        if($query->execute()) {
            $media = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NAMED);
            $media['media_is_read'] = true;
            $newRes = makeResultResponseWithObject($res, 200, $media);
        } else {
            $newRes = makeResultResponseWithString($res, 400, $query->errorInfo()[2]);
        }
    } else {
        $newRes = makeResultResponseWithString($res, 400, $query->errorInfo()[2]);
    }
} else {
    $newRes = makeResultResponseWithString($res, 401, 'Your token has expired. Please login again.');
}

return $newRes; }
```

Comment: and what is the error you get?

Comment: As Target is not writable , it has no permission to save the file, make the folder where you are moving/coping the file writable. (like chmod 777 folderpath , or add the www-data user to that folder and provide group read write access)

Comment: yes this is what I saw online but I have little backend experience so I was curious of there was a recommendation on how to find this folder to rectify it

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that `assets/images/` is writable by your webserver

In you're hosting on a Ubuntu/Debian platform, most likely this will work:

`$ cd {root directory of your project}
$ mkdir -p assets/images
$ chgrp www-data assets/images
$ chmod g+rws assets/images`

Comment: In my case folder does not exists.